# Dynamically generating elements out of a dynamically generated form with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I working on a to-do list that is able to create projects and can also add tasks inside these projects.
For the moment I'm able to generate the new project element and a form to create tasks inside these projects.

This is the markup I'm using:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="link">Projects</li>
        <li class="link">Due today</li>
        <li class="link">Priority</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="add-item">+ New Project</button>
    <div class="new-project">
        <form class="add-project">
            <h3>New Project</h3>
            <label for="project-name">Project Name: </label><br>
            <input class="project-input" type="text" name="project-name" required><br>
            <label for="project-desc">Description: </label><br>
            <input class="project-input" type="text-area" name="project-desc" required><br>
            <input class="submit-project"type="submit" value="+ Add Project">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="to-do">
            <h2 class="to-do-title">Title</h2>
            <p class="to-do-description">Description</p>
            <form class="new-task">
                <h3>New Task</h3>

                <label for="task-name">Task Name: </label><br>
                <input class="task-input" type="text" name="task-name"> 
                <br>

                <label for="task-date">Due-Date: </label><br>
                <input class="task-input" type="date" name="task-date"> 
                <br>

                <label for="priority">Priority: </label><br>
                <select class="task-input-dd" name="priority">
                    <option value="high">high</option>
                    <option value="medium">medium</option>
                    <option value="low">low</option>
                </select><br>
                <input id="btn" class="add-task" type="submit" value="+ Add Task">
            </form>
            <button class="dlt-prjct">Delete Project</button>
            <div class="task-list">
                <span class="task-text">
                    <p class="task-desc">Finish Math Assignment</p>
                    <p class="due-date">23/22/21</p>
                    <div class="check-form">
                        <div class="task-footer">
                            <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="done-task">
                        </div>
                        <div class="task-footer">
                            <i class="far fa-flag"></i>
                            <span class="task-priority">HIGH</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <button class="delete-task"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the function that I'm using to create the project elements:

```
const projectForm = document.querySelector('.add-project')
projectForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const projectName = projectForm.querySelector('input[name="project-name"]').value;
    const projectDesc = projectForm.querySelector('input[name="project-desc"]').value;

    const addProject = document.querySelector('.projects');
    const newProject = document.createElement('div');
    newProject.className += 'to-do';
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.className += 'to-do-title';
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.className += 'to-do-description';
    h2.innerHTML = `${projectName}`;
    p.innerHTML = `${projectDesc}`;
    const deleteProject = document.createElement('button');
    deleteProject.className += 'dlt-prjct';
    deleteProject.innerHTML = 'Delete Project';

    addProject.appendChild(newProject);
    newProject.appendChild(h2);
    newProject.appendChild(p);
    createNewProjectForm(newProject);
    newProject.appendChild(deleteProject);
});
```

And this is the function I'm using to create the form that goes inside the project element:

```
function createNewProjectForm(attatchTo){
    const createForm = document.createElement('form')
    createForm.className += 'new-task';
    const h3 = document.createElement('h3')
    h3.innerText = 'New Task'

    // label plus input field for TASK-NAME: 
    const taskInputLabel = document.createElement('label');
    taskInputLabel.setAttribute('for', 'task-name');
    taskInputLabel.innerHTML = 'Task Name: ';

    const taskInput = document.createElement('input');
    taskInput.className += 'task-input';
    taskInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    taskInput.setAttribute('name', 'task-name');

    // label plus input field for DUE-DATE:
    const dateInputLabel = document.createElement('label');
    dateInputLabel.setAttribute('for', 'task-date');
    dateInputLabel.innerHTML = 'Due Date: ';

    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');
    dateInput.className += 'task-input';
    dateInput.setAttribute('type', 'date');
    dateInput.setAttribute('name', 'task-date');

    //create the SELECT menu
    const selectLabel = document.createElement('label');
    selectLabel.setAttribute('for', 'priority');
    selectLabel.innerHTML = 'Priority: ';

    const select = document.createElement('select');
    select.className += 'task-input-dd';
    select.setAttribute('name', 'priority');

    //create OPTIONS for the select menu
    const optionOne = document.createElement("option");
    optionOne.setAttribute('value', 'high')
    optionOne.text = "high";
    const optionTwo = document.createElement("option");
    optionTwo.setAttribute('value', 'medium')
    optionTwo.text = "medium";
    const optionThree = document.createElement("option");
    optionThree.setAttribute('value', 'low')
    optionThree.text = "low";

    //add OPTIONS to the SELECT menu
    select.add(optionOne)
    select.add(optionTwo)
    select.add(optionThree)

    //add the SUBMIT button
    const submitBtn = document.createElement('input');
    submitBtn.className += 'add-task';
    submitBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    submitBtn.setAttribute('value', '+ Add Task');

    //FINALLY, APPEND the elements Together to the form
    createForm.appendChild(h3)
    createForm.appendChild(taskInputLabel);
    createForm.appendChild(taskInput);
    createForm.appendChild(dateInputLabel);
    createForm.appendChild(dateInput);
    createForm.appendChild(selectLabel);
    createForm.appendChild(select);
    createForm.appendChild(submitBtn);
    attatchTo.appendChild(createForm);
};
```

What I'm having trouble with is that when I'm trying to append a new task inside the project element, the whole page reloads and nothing gets generated.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
const taskForm = document.querySelector('.new-task')
taskForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const taskName = taskForm.querySelector('input[name="task-name"]').value
    const taskDate = taskForm.querySelector('input[name="task-date"]').value
    const taskPriority = taskForm.querySelector('select[name="priority"]').value
    const addTask = document.querySelector('.to-do');
    const newTask = document.createElement('div');
    newTask.className += 'task-list'
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className += 'task-text';
    const p1 = document.createElement('p');
    p1.className += 'task-desc';
    p1.innerHTML = `${taskName}`;
    const p2 = document.createElement('p');
    p2.className += 'due-date';
    p2.innerHTML = `${taskDate}`;
    const div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.className += 'check-form';
    const divTask1 = document.createElement('div');
    divTask1.className += 'task-footer';
    const check1 = document.createElement('i');
    check1.className += 'far fa-check-circle';
    const checkbox1 = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox1.className += 'done-task'
    checkbox1.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    const divTask2 = document.createElement('div');
    divTask2.className += 'task-footer';
    const check2 = document.createElement('i');
    check2.className += 'far fa-flag';
    const spanFooter = document.createElement('span');
    spanFooter.className += 'task-priority';
    spanFooter.innerHTML = `${taskPriority}`;
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.className += 'delete-task';
    const trashBin = document.createElement('i');
    trashBin.className += 'fas fa-trash-alt';
    addTask.appendChild(newTask);
    newTask.appendChild(span);
    span.appendChild(p1);
    span.appendChild(p2);
    span.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(divTask1);
    divTask1.appendChild(check1);
    divTask1.appendChild(checkbox1);
    div1.appendChild(divTask2);
    divTask2.appendChild(check2);
    divTask2.appendChild(spanFooter);
    newTask.appendChild(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.appendChild(trashBin);
});
```

I've been reading and I think that I'm dealing with a problem of DOM event delegation but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to apply that in this project. I've also seen some JQuery possible solutions but I'm trying to solve this with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use
e.preventDefault(); on the submit event